# Value of Table 1 needs to be permanent after changing value of inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, material-ui

I am new to React and am trying to add table rows on the click of a button. The problem is that the values in the input labels are getting added to the table. but the values need to be unchanged on adding another row. As soon as I change the value in the inputs the corresponding table row values also change. I want the table values to be permanent and different according to changing input in input labels.

Here is my code for KPI Details:

```
export class KPIDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [],
    idx: [1]
  };
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  //2
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      KPI_Before: "",
      UOM_Before: "",
      Base_Before: "",
      Target_Before: "",
      dateTime: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  //3
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  setDate = dateTime => this.setState({ dateTime });

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    const {
      values: {
        Title,
        Details,
        What,
        Why,
        How,
        Status,
        Cost,
        Benefits,
        Kpi_Before,
        Kpi_After,
        UOM_Before,
        Base_Before,
        Target_Before,
        Time,
        dateTime
      }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                  gutterBottom
                  align="center"
                  style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  KPI Before Implementation
                </Typography>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <TextField
                label="KPI"
                id="Kpi_Before"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                placeholder="Enter the KPI"
                onChange={handleChange("Kpi_Before")}
                defaultValue={values.Kpi_Before}
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
                <InputLabel
                  htmlFor="UOM_Before"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    top: "50%",
                    transform: "translate(0,-50%"
                  }}
                >
                  UOM
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="UOM_Before"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={handleChange("UOM_Before")}
                  defaultValue={values.UOM_Before}
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputProps={{
                    id: "UOM_Before"
                  }}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="Nos">Nos</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Percentage">Percentage</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Metric">Metric</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <TextField
                label="Base Level"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                placeholder="Enter the Base Level"
                onChange={handleChange("Base_Before")}
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <TextField
                label="Target Level"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                placeholder="Enter the Target Level"
                onChange={handleChange("Target_Before")}
                defaultValue={values.Target_Before}
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Target Date"
                type="date"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                onChange={handleChange("dateTime")}
                style={{ width: "67%" }}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
              />

              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                onClick={this.handleAddRow}
                size="small"
                style={styles.button}
              >
                +
              </Button>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={6}>
              ...
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
              <table
                className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                id="tab_logic"
              >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Kpi_Before"
                          value={Kpi_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="UOM_Before"
                          value={UOM_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Base_Before"
                          value={Base_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Target_Before"
                          value={Target_Before}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="Target_Before"
                          value={dateTime}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button
                onClick={this.handleRemoveRow}
                className="pull-right btn btn-default"
              >
                Delete Row
              </button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: purple
  },
  status: {
    danger: "orange"
  }
});

const styles = {
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    verticalAlign: "bottom"
  }
};

export default KPIDetails;
```

Here is my code for User Form:

```
export class UserForm extends Component {

  state = {
    step: 1,
    Title: "",
    Details: "",
    What: "",
    Why: "",
    How: "",
    Status: "",
    Cost: "",
    Benefits: "",
    Kpi_Before: "",
    Kpi_After: "",
    Time: "",
    UOM_Before: "",
    Base_Before: "",
    Target_Before: "",
    dateTime: null,
    rows: []
  };

  //1
  handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { Kpi_Before, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [Kpi_Before]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  //2
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      KPI_Before: "",
      UOM_Before: "",
      Base_Before: "",
      Target_Before: "",
      dateTime: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  //3
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };

  //Proceed to next step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  //Go back to previous step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  //Handle fields change
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const {
      Title,
      Details,
      What,
      Why,
      How,
      Status,
      Cost,
      Benefits,
      Kpi_Before,
      Kpi_After,
      Time,
      UOM_Before,
      Base_Before,
      Target_Before,
      dateTime,
      rows
    } = this.state;

    const values = {
      Title,
      Details,
      What,
      Why,
      How,
      Status,
      Cost,
      Benefits,
      Kpi_Before,
      Kpi_After,
      Time,
      UOM_Before,
      Base_Before,
      Target_Before,
      dateTime,
      rows
    };
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <FormUserDetails
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <KPIDetails
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChangeRows={this.handleChangeRows}
            handleAddRow={this.handleAddRow}
            handleRemoveRow={this.handleRemoveRow}
          />
        );

      case 3:
        return (
          <Confirm
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 4:
        return <Success />;
    }
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Please Advice me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Used defaultValue instead of value and it solved the problem

Comment: Even if you answer your own question it would be useful for the community if you share with us the solution with a bit more depth and with some explanation, maybe you could help someone who's encountered the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this so I am not totally clear on the concepts.

The traditional HTML forms where you use JavaScript/jQuery to get the values from its input elements are the typical forms with uncontrolled components. There is no explicit use of state variables and no implementation of any event handler whatsoever to update the input values. So, inserting onChange() to the uncontrolled  component in this case will be unnecessary. Their values are just what we type in. In react When the form is submitted, the reference to the  element is achieved via the current attribute of the attached ref. So, the value which the user enters can be had with current.value.

In the lifecycle of React's rendering, the value attributes in the form elements overrides the values in the DOM. To handle such cases, React came up with the defaultValue attribute, which specifies the initial value but leave the ensuing updates uncontrolled.

React treats inputs as either controlled (value bound with prop/state), or uncontrolled (no binding on value).

When I was using value in my form like this:

```
                    <td>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="Base_Before"
                      value={Base_Before}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                  </td>
```

its value would automatically change on changing the input field . So everytime I updated and added rows to the table its value would always reflect the value in the input field.
Defaultvalue does not update the state on updating the input value so value once entered in one row will stay permanent and not change with the change in the input field.

Again I am new to react and this is what I understood, so correct me if I am wrong and hope this helps